# How do I get the current domain/origin in Nuxt's `server/api`

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I have a frontend that requests different data depending on the origin of the request.
It works fine within the composition scope.
Now I would like to generate a sitemap.xml and the only solutions I found are using an `eventHandler` within `server/api`. Here I'm not able to get the current origin. In fact I have no headers at all.

Here is what I tried so far:

```js
export default eventHandler(async (event) => {
    const { req, res } = event;
    console.log(event.node.req.headers);
})
```

I also tried to get the origin from my state (I'm using Pinia)

```js
export default eventHandler(async (event) => {
    const setupStore = useSetupStore();
    console.log(setupStore);
})
```

In this case; useSetupStore is not defined

Answer (score 0):

files located at `server/` run completely as a standalone server which means it cannot access components coming from nuxt or pinia

https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/server

Comment: thanks.. my main goal would be to get the Origin entry from the headers. 
pinia would be only a workaround anyway

Comment: you can directly read it from the database or the `node:fs` module from the data source

Comment: What do you mean? How can I get the current origin from a database or the filesystem?

Comment: I would need to write it to a database/filesystem in the first place, or not?

Comment: @GordonFreeman you can confirm the data from the route, but I'm not sure you plan to do with it you're creating a sitemap, huh? or do something else depending on the intention of you take the different approach

Comment: the same frontend is used by many different customers with different domains. depending on the domain (header: origin) the frontend initializes with different content, different routes, etc. now i need a way to generate an individual sitemap.xml for every requesting domain on demand. hence the need for the header: origin